# Rational Function Integration

Tags: integration, rational-functions

This looks to be a simple problem, but it has me stumped. I already have the answer, but a step-by-step solution would be appreciated.

$$\int\frac{x+4}{x^2+2x+5}$$

Comment: Have you tried completing the square in the denominator?

Comment: Yeah, its $((x+1)^2+4)$

Comment: My problem is what to do afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To elaborate on my comments:
$$\begin{align*}
\int\frac{x+4}{(x+1)^2+4}\,dx&=\int\frac{x+1}{(x+1)^2+4}\,dx+\int\frac{3}{(x+1)^2+4}\,dx\\[1ex]
&=\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{2x+2}{(x+1)^2+4}\,dx+\frac{3}{2}\int\frac{\sec^2t}{(2\tan t)^2+4}\,dt\\[1ex]
&=\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{du}{u}+\frac{3}{2}\int\frac{\sec^2t}{(2\tan t)^2+4}\,dt
\end{align*}$$
The first integral should be obvious. The second will be, too, after some simplification.

Comment: Thanks! I'm hitting myself for not seeing this.